# It is showing "Collected 0 items" while i am using correct naming convention

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am creating hybrid framework from scratch, i am trying to run my both test cases, i have install all necessary package, but when i am running my `test_login.py` file using command `pytest -v -s TestCases/test_Login.py`
it is not showing any error but it is showing

> "Collected 0 items"

I have tried almost all the suggestions of respected user, i am also using the correct naming convention and i have also try using different commands but i am unable to execute my all test cases.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons for this, and we don't have enough information here. However, the problem seems that pytest can't discover tests. A few things you might try:

Use `pyproject.toml` file and `testpaths` option:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = "tests"
```

`tests` here is the directory to be checked.

And run `pytest` in the command line from the directory where `pyproject.toml` resides.

I don't see classes in the screenshot. Your class should be `Test` prefixed.

Or you can define options in the `pyproject.toml` file such as:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files = test_*.py
python_classes = Test
python_functions = *_test
```

You can also try VSC. It has `pytest` functionality.

These are a few ideas that came into my mind for trying.